# Morphia: Search for null values in a list of embedded objects

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a list of embedded entities:

```
@Embedded
private List<EmbeddedEntity> embedded = new ArrayList<EmbeddedEntity>();
```

In this list, I want to search for any embedded entity which has a specific attribute (let's call it `foo`), but not another one (`bar`). So `foo` should be non-null and `bar` null in Java / inexistant in MongoDB.

I tried the following code (I do have the UUID of the `Entity` containing the list):

```
Query<Entity> query = mongoDataStore.find(Entity.class).field("uuid").equal(uuid)
    .field("embedded.foo").exists()
    .field("embedded.bar").doesNotExist();
```

This works correctly if the list is empty or has a single entry (where `foo` has a value and `bar` does not yet exist). But as soon as any `bar` attribute has a value, the query returns the wrong result. So I'm looking for a query, which iterates through all the embedded entities and fires on any missing `bar`. Is that possible?

Example data:

```
// the query does not pick up the entity as it doesn't have a foo -
// that's what I want
{ uuid: "...", [ { embedded: } ] }

// the query picks up the entity as there is a foo but no bar -
// that's what I want
{ uuid: "...", [ { embedded: { foo: date } } ] }

// the query does not pick up the entity - that's not what I want
// as one foo has a value and its bar doesn't
{ uuid: "...", [ { embedded: { foo: date, bar: date } },
                 { embedded: { foo: date } }
               ] }
```

PS: I get the same result with `.field("embedded.bar").hasThisOne(null)`.

PPS: Manually iterating through the list elements is not really an option, as I want to use the query for an update operation.

PPS: I think this is a bug in Morphia - see my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9705175/573153) for a workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a workaround. While I don't seem to be able to query on null, I can query for a specific value.

In my case, the `bar` field is a Date. So I can initialize the entity with `private Date bar = new Date(0)` - this is clearly an invalid date in my case, which is never used. So the query then looks like this:

```
Query<Entity> query = mongoDataStore
    .find(Entity.class)
    .field("uuid").equal(uuid)
    .field("embedded.foo").exists()
    .field("embedded.bar").hasThisOne(new Date(0));
```

And in case anyone needs it, here is the update operation (you need to disable the validation as `.$.` will otherwise raise an error):

```
UpdateOperations<Entity> update = mongoDataStore
    .createUpdateOperations(Entity.class)
    .disableValidation()
    .set("embedded.$.bar", new Date());

mongoDataStore.update(query, update);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a conceptual problem with your schema. Remember that you always query for top level documents. The reason your query isn't working is because you're asking it to return **top level** documents where **at least one** of the elements has foo and **at least one** of the elements does not have a bar value. Note that both conditions need not apply on the same array element.

You can do what you want in MongoDB using a $elemMatch :

`find({embedded:{$elemMatch:{foo:{$exists:true}, bar:{$exists:false}}}})` as demonstrated here :

```
> db.test.save({embedded:[]})
> db.test.save({embedded:[{foo:1}]})
> db.test.save({embedded:[{bar:1}]})
> db.test.save({embedded:[{foo:1, bar:1}]})
> db.test.find({embedded:{$elemMatch:{foo:{$exists:true}, bar:{$exists:false}}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f60c4d56fa40267a11d2f2c"), "embedded" : [ { "foo" : 1 } ] }
```

If "null" is a valid value for bar you can simply change it to :

```
> db.test.save({embedded:[{foo:1, bar:null}]})
> db.test.find({embedded:{$elemMatch:{foo:{$exists:true}, $or:[{bar:{$exists:false}}, {bar:null}]}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f60c4d56fa40267a11d2f2c"), "embedded" : [ { "foo" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f60c52a6fa40267a11d2f30"), "embedded" : [ { "foo" : 1, "bar" : null } ] }
```

Now, in Morphia the $elemMatch is wrapped by the FieldEnd method "hasThisElement". I'm not that familiar with Morphia (I wrote and use my own mapper) but this should take a DBObject with the above clause as it's value and that should result in what you need to do.

But again, this will return the top level documents that have elements in their embedded array that match these criteria. If you only want to return the matching elements you may have to turn your embedded structure in a top-level collection. It will be sufficient if your update only involves modifying the matching element(s) through the $ positional operator though :

```
db.test.update(
    {embedded:{$elemMatch:{foo:{$exists:true}, $or:[{bar:{$exists:false}}, {bar:null}]}}},
    {$set:{'embedded.$.bar':"yay!"}}
)
```

Comment: "you're asking it to return top level documents where at least one of the elements has foo and at least one of the elements does not have a bar value. Note that both conditions need not apply on the same array element." That's exactly what I want - they don't need to be on the same element. The above query fails if **any** of the bar fields has a value. And I want to get the top-level collection, that's sufficient.

Comment: Hm, in that case your requirement is a bit unclear to me. Can you extend your original post with sample data and what you want as the result of your query? Much like I did in my answer. It makes for a easier reading. And what do you mean by "failing"? Not returning results when it should? Throwing errors? Returning results when it shouldn't?

Comment: I've tried to clarified and added an example. And my anser below produces the desired result...

Comment: In that case my solution should still work. You have to use $elemMatch or the Morphia equivalent of one. This will scan per element and allows you to query for "at least one element that has foo but not bar but can have other elements that does have both"

Comment: Morphias equivalent for ``$elemMatch`` is ``.hasThisElement(value)``. However, ``.field("embedded.bar").hasThisElement(null);`` chokes up an error, because the value is null. This is probably a Morphia issue rather than related to MongoDB, but thanks for clarifying this on the database level!

Comment: While I still think my answer is the correct workaround, I've awarded you the 50 points for your efforts - thanks again!

Comment: @xeraa I think you're missing what you need to do with hasThisElement. You shouldn't pass null for just "bar" but the entire element filter for "embedded". So field("embedded").hasThisElement(foo exists, bar doesnt as DBObject). Pretty sure my answer is actually correct but I'll double check with one of the Morphia creators if he doesn't run into this thread himself ;)